# Terminal 'incognito mode'?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, configuration, console, history

I use Terminal a lot, and sometimes I am running commands, which aren't things I don't want others to see, but more commands that if I accidentally arrowed up to and accidentally executed would cause a lot of trouble.

So I am wondering if there is, or I can make, some sort of Terminal 'incognito mode' which would allow me to, upon the execution of a certain command, stop recording my history, and then only start recording after I either execute a start recording history again command and exit 'incognito mode', or I simply restart the Terminal?

Because I find myself later on going and removing stuff from my `.bash_history`, when it would be much easier if I could have stopped it recording there in the first place, or at least got it to try to record it somewhere where it just wouldn't be allowed to, and would just end up not recording it.

Comment: Well, presumably you are **paranoid** that your history will be read by others?

Comment: @Sparhawk: Well, it's partly that, and party I don't want to accidentally execute a possibly deadly maintenance command when I'm just arrowing up in the future! :D

Comment: Just to add, you don't have to justify yourself: *"which aren't things I don't want others to see"*. That would be a perfectly valid reason to me too. (Especially in this time and age where everybody tries to make you look guilty for having "things to hide")

Comment: If you open two tabs, do stuff in the first one, do stuff in the second one, then close the second one BEFORE the first one, only the history of the first one seems to be written to `.bash_history`. (Ubuntu 15.04 ruined Terminal, lucky this is a live USB.)

Comment: See this question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/48769/avoid-to-keep-command-in-history)

Comment: It would also be handy for commands or programs which required you to enter your password or some secure credentials onto the CLI which them become stored in you .bash_history

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555462/how-can-i-open-a-read-only-bash-shell. Incognito mode beyond history

Answer (score 283, accepted):

**Run a command without putting it in history:**

Simply put a space before the command. Bash will ignore commands with a prepended space:

Example: <kbd>Space</kbd>`echo "Some secret text"`

Note: This only works if the `HISTCONTROL` variable is set to `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`.

---

**Disable history temporarily:**

- Run <kbd>Space</kbd>`set +o history` or <kbd>Space</kbd>`shopt -uo history` to disable history.
- Run `set -o history` or `shopt -so history` to enable it again.

---

**Disable history for the current session (won't remember any commands from the session):**

```
unset HISTFILE
```

Note: You'll be able to see the commands pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> until you close the terminal.

---

**Remove a command from the history:**

Run <kbd>Space</kbd>`history | grep "part of your secret command"`

It will show a list of previously ran commands, in this format:

```
user@host:~$  history | grep pkill
  302  pkill $$
  467  pkill gone-cal
  468  pkill actionaz
  500  pkill chrome
  550  pkill super
```

Select the entry number at the left of the command. You can copy it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Run <kbd>Space</kbd>`history -d <number>` where `<number>` is the entry number to remove the entry.
You can paste that number with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

---

**Other interesting answers:**

- [@echristopherson](https://askubuntu.com/a/626309/387382)
- [@MoithilBiswas](https://askubuntu.com/a/625708/387382)
- [@dolt](https://askubuntu.com/a/625842/387382)

Comment: If you use `history -d` to remove a line, this will remove the content of the line, but you can never remove the fact that you ran `history -d` (unless you first use `set +o history` before running `history -d`)

Comment: It just reminded me of the super-injunction logic, that's all ;)

Comment: @AJFaraday: Sorry, I don't understood your comment, English is not my mother tongue. Can you explain me it?

Comment: (OT) Injunctions are a legal document which keeps people from publishing something. A super injunction also keeps them from publishing the fact they were denied the ability to publish. Some logical arguments ask if they can publish that they were denied the ability to publish some information. Then it becomes a cyclical argument.

Comment: @AJFaraday:  **;-)** Now I understood, thanks. Yes, you had reason. Lol.

Comment: @Helio I've made some quite drastic formatting changes to your answer. I personally think it makes it easier to read - and easier for people to understand your meaning (the Space+Command syntax was confusing for me). Feel free to do a partial / full rollback if you disagree.

Comment: @Tim: I partially agree with your changes... I  think that `Space`, being a non-printable character, is best to represent it with something "solid", and more being on the start of a line...  I agree with the sample output of `history`. I partially agree with the *slow* copy/paste method. I'll partially revert your changes. Feel free of revert my reversion if do you have another opinion **;-)**

Comment: @Helio I think it's better for users to know the "proper" way to copy - especially if they accidentally go and select some text. I'm not sure how to do the space, maybe clarify more that the space is there? The [space] looks a little clumsy to me...

Comment: And how to clarify a blank character?

Comment: The `unset HISTFILE` approach also works retroactively for all commands which haven't been written to `.bash_history` yet.

Comment: @kasperd: Thanks! Feel free to edit my answer to clarify that if my edit doesn't suffice.

Comment: "remind" should be "remember"

Comment: @A.Donda, sorry, English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 44):

You can simply delete the history **of one particular terminal session** by adding command `history -cw` after working.

Do not close the terminal before giving this command.

Comment: This will not remove all the history?

Comment: This will only remove history of that particular terminal session.

Comment: Be aware. This command cleared my .zsh_history.

Answer (score 30):

[`shopt -uo history`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18663518/12870) should do it best.

Nuking the `HISTFILE` (et al) variables won't stop your <kbd>Up</kbd> history being logged, it just won't push it to disk. This may or may not be a positive thing for you, but given you mention it, I guess you want something better. Changing the `shopt` history setting stops the whole history mechanism from triggering.

You can turn logging back on with `shopt -so history` (the `-s` and `-u` are set and unset respectively).

Note that the command itself will probably be logged so prepend it with a space to stop it being added to the history before you clear the variable.

Answer (score 19):

Another way to kill the current shell without logging to the history file is to do:

```
kill -9 $$
```

This causes bash (and probably other shells too) to send the SIGKILL signal to itself, killing it on the spot and preventing it from writing anything to disk.

Comment: a.k.a. 'Shoot yourself in the head' :). This has the advantage that you don't need to remember to do anything before writing the commands.

Comment: I use zsh with incremental history write, so I doubt this would work in my case

Answer (score 14):

To temporary disable the command history for the current session, you can temporarily unset the HISTFILE environment variable.

```
unset HISTFILE
```

while the session is active you can access the history as usual, but it won’t be saved to the disk.

To reverse in the same session (all changes will be recorded)

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history
```

Comment: And is there an easy way in the current session to reverse this, and make it carry on?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I added a command for reverting in the current session.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Why you need a command to set `HISTFILE` again on the current session? If do you undo the change (even after running the secret commands) they will be stored into history when you exit.

Comment: @Helio: Oh, no, I meant a command which would then start recording again, but not save the commands which I didn't want it to save.

Comment: Then `unset HISTFILE` nor `HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history` will work. Check the Oli answer or mine.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, Helio seems to be right on this one as the history is saved on exit. I had not considered that one.

Answer (score 10):

You can modify history lines in the current shell session. If you walk back through history (e.g. with <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and change a line *without executing it*, only the modified version of the line will be saved. You can modify it in any way you like; good choices would include using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to totally blank the line or using <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> to put a `#` comment character at the beginning.

To leave behind a line without executing it, remember not to hit <kbd>Return</kbd> (<kbd>Enter</kbd>). What I do is return to the newest line in history via <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>></kbd>.

(Instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>></kbd>, in most terminals you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>></kbd>; the same goes for the <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> suggestion above.)

**Note:** You can’t permanently modify entries from previous sessions this way. Those changes will not be applied to the `HISTFILE` at the end of the session.

Answer (score 6):

You could also make .bash_history read-only. I would empty the file first and then do:

```
 chattr +i .bash_history
```

Answer (score 5):

You could execute the sensitive commands in a screen session, then destroy the session when you are done.

Alternately, you could keep that screen session alive but detached, and only access it when you actually want to be able to up arrow to the otherwise dangerous commands.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use `mksh`, and this shell by default has no history file. That means you could launch alternative shell such as `mksh` or `dash` (which comes by default by the way) to run the command you don't want users to see, and exit once done. `bash` history will only record that you launched alternative shell and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use terminal multiplexer such as `tmux`, `screen`. So under `tmux` or `screen` history would not be saved.