# How to run an anonymous terminal session?

Tags: command-line, server, history, bash-history

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/625277/146980) by [Paranoid Panda](https://askubuntu.com/users/364819/paranoid-panda) asks about incognito terminal use. This means history is not recorded in `bash_history`; so you can't access commands that were entered during that session.
However this only makes you 'incognito' on *your own* system, not to anyone else.

Is it possible to run an *anonymous* terminal session, so that any network-related commands entered in the command-line can not be traced back to the original user, for example the data packets I send to repos/sites/servers?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a proxy?

Comment: Then this isn't related to the terminal or shell at all. For network anonymity, you'd use a VPN or a proxy or a system-wide Tor.

Comment: Also unless you communicate your username or identity to the servers, they will only know your IP address, not your real name or even user account name.

Comment: @LéoLam I **don't want** them to see my IP address...

Comment: As said above, you'll want to use a system-wide VPN or Tor then. Keep in mind that the IP is not something which was designed to be kept secret -- servers need it to send data back to you. You don't just get hacked if someone knows your IP, and sites cannot associate an IP with a person (again, unless you log in or have a profile on that site) but I suppose you know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible as the server needs your data to answer your requests. And you cannot force them to not save that data.