# clear terminal critical outputs

Tags: command-line, bash, password, security

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my win10, and I usually create my password with this line of code:

```
echo -n "<some text generated by hand from the site's domains>" | sha256sum |cut -c-20
```

But today I accidentally pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>   after the echo command.

Does Ubuntu save its terminal outputs in a file? Am I safe just using the `clear` command?

Do you guys recommend a better solution so my password is different from each other and hard to compute a new one based on some of my other passwords?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not exactly an answer, so posting this as a comment: You could use `stty -echo; tr -d '\n' | sha256sum | cut -c-20; stty echo` instead and then paste the password to stdin, press enter and ctrl-d. This way you get the same result, but nothing recorded in your history or scrollback buffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal 'incognito mode'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625277/terminal-incognito-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *output* of the command is usually *not* stored anywhere and closing the window is enough. But the command itself is stored: in the shell's history.

To remove it from there it is best to first close *all* terminal windows. Normally, the history is written to the file `~/.bash_history` when the shell ends and directly manipulating the file won't help because it gets overwritten upon shell's exit. There are ways to configure `history` differently but the easiest is to simply close all terminal windows.

Now open *one* new terminal window and type

```
history
```

or

```
history | grep echo
```

Sample output:

```
...
2007  echo -n "<some text generated by hand from the site's domains>" | sha256sum |cut -c-20 
2008  echo -n "secret" | sha256sum |cut -c-20 
2009  echo -n "secret"
2010  history
```

Here you see that not only the "malicious" command is stored but also the "correct" one. You can delete it with

```
history -d 2009
```

where `2009` is the number in the first column. Change that appropriately. Now:

```
history
...
2007  echo -n "<some text generated by hand from the site's domains>" | sha256sum |cut -c-20 
2008  echo -n "secret" | sha256sum |cut -c-20 
2009  history
2010  history -d 2009
2011  history
```

For the future you might want to prefix your `echo … | sha256sum …` with a space, i.e.

```
_echo -n "secret" | sha256sum |cut -c-20   # The '_' indicates a leading space
```

This way the complete command won't be recorded in the history. The behaviour is controlled by the HISTCONTROL variable ([`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)):

> HISTCONTROL
>
> A colon-separated  list  of values controlling how commands are saved on
>   the history list. **If the list of values includes `ignorespace`, lines
>   which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list.** A
>   value of `ignoredups` causes lines matching the previous history entry
>   to not be saved. A value of `ignoreboth` is shorthand for `ignorespace`
>   and `ignoredups`.

You may want to add `export HISTCONTROL='ignoreboth'` to your `~/.bashrc` to achieve that.

Comment: While the terminal is still open, you can also remove the line directly from the history in memory, which hasn't been saved to disk yet. Use `history -c` to clear the complete history of the respective shell session, or `history` to show the list and `history -d NUMBER` to delete only the entry with the specific NUMBER in the list.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, the `history` command has quite a lot of useful options. I just thought closing all windows might be the easiest. We could also setup HISTIGNORE so that `echo … sha256sum … | cut` lines aren't recorded at all (no matter the leading space).

Comment: thanks man(for the output part)
(i already knew about space button and i remember typing it to my question but it's not there :) ,but still a thanks)